# add watermark to webcam images with cronjob

Tags: php, image, cron, webcam, watermark

Would be great to learn something here by contribution. I am not experienced in programming but willing to improve my skills. I have a webcam that sends a picture every hour on our webserver via FTP with the timestamp (cameraname-yyyymmddhhmmss.jpg) in the filename.

Best solution IMO would be, if I have a cronjob that looks for the newest picture in the folder with all the pictures and makes a copy of the newest one in another directory with the filename 'newest.jpg'. Then the cronjob should add a watermark with our logo on that picture to serve it for the public.

If I get that done I need another cronjob to delete most of the original pictures with the timestamp but keep one picture from every day to create a small timelaps-movie.

Can this be done in the way I think?
Cheers, Mathias

Comment: Certainly that is possible. There are many many examples for both, usage of cron jobs and watermarking of images here on StackOverflow. Just take a look at them. Oh, and one additional remark: the usual strategy for data processing is _not_ to modify the original data, but only the versions you actually hand out. For this you would simply apply the watermark on the fly when an image is requested, whilst you keep the unmodified versions in your file system. For performance reasons you can maintain a simple cache directory so that the watermark has to be applied only once per image.

Comment: I progress slowly but I had successes. I have a cronjob that picks the newest picture and saves it an "neu.jpg". This cronjob is running every 5 minutes.

Comment: `<?php
chdir("/home/www/web299/html/webcam/PX-3786_00626E588856/snap/");
$newfile = "/home/www/web299/html/webcam/neu.jpg";
$lastModifiedTime = 0;
$lastModifiedFile = '';
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && preg_match("/jpg$/",$file ) ) {
            if(filectime($file) > $lastModifiedTime){
                $lastModifiedTime = filectime($file);
                $lastModifiedFile = $file;
            }
        }
       copy($lastModifiedFile, $newfile);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>`

Comment: Please add new details and additional information right in the question above (there is an `edit` button below it). That was things stay readable :-)